# How to add some nodes to existing cluster on Cassandra in Docker

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm using latest default image of Cassandra in Docker. In Cassandra I have one keyspace with my data. What I want to do is to add some nodes and change replication factor. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using an orchestration layer like Kubernetes?  Or just Docker (Desktop?)?

Comment: Just desktop, local version of Docker, on MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to do this, you'll need two Cassandra containers running on your Mac.  You'll also need to set specific container names, so that they can be used as the "seed" list for both.

Bitnami has a good doc on how to do this, just page down halfway to the "Setting up a cluster" section:

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/cassandra/

Basically, you create a specific network.  All containers on the same network should be able to talk to each other.  In theory, you *could* skip this step and your containers would run on the "default" network.  But creating a specific network is good practice.

```
docker network create cassandra_network
```

Create the first node like this:

```
docker run --name cassandra-node1 \
  --net=cassandra_network \
  -p 9042:9042 \
  -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassandra-cluster \
  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-node1,cassandra-node2 \
  bitnami/cassandra:latest
```

If you don't want the "latest" (or don't want to use Bitnami's image) then you can swap out the last line with this to get the community image and whichever version:

```
cassandra:4.0.1
```

Watch the log to make sure it comes up.  Then create the second node with the same command, but alter the name.

```
docker run --name cassandra-node2 \
  --net=cassandra_network \
  -p 9042:9042 \
  -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassandra-cluster \
  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-node1,cassandra-node2 \
  bitnami/cassandra:latest
```

Once the second node is up and joined, you can adjust your keyspace replication (depending on your data center name):

```
ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH
    replication={'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','dc1':'2'};
```

Or for `SimpleStrategy`:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH
    replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'};
```

Including the community documentation for reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I managed to solve the problems on Monday in a similar way to yours, however there is one, maybe significant, difference beetwen our solutions. You set CASSANDRA_SEEDS to both 'cassandra-node1' and 'cassandra-node2'. In my solution I set it only on node 2 and node 3 to the equivalent  of yours 'cassandra-node1' which is the main node created as the first.  So in my node 1 I haven't set this CASSANDRA_SEEDS and both node 2 and node 3 have CASSANDRA_SEEDS = 'cassandra-node1'. Is my solution the wrong one? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Vader20FF nah, your solution is just fine.  Seed nodes don't really matter too much.  As long as the nodes can find each other, it's all good!